# Convert animated gif to one image with Rmagic (image magic)

Tags: ruby, carrierwave, rmagick

I know there is a way to convert several images to gif animation with Rmagic, however I want to do the opposite. When uploading an animated gif, I want it to  be non-animated, how can I do that ? (single/any image from image stream is good enough)

I'll use this as a part of [carrierwave](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave&ei=zB5cUeM8r5rUBcL2gKgJ&usg=AFQjCNFD144z6Z-4eSvqdq-AD1XZrLgEWg&sig2=TQlJIhVYgiyzRxUFGYw42A&bvm=bv.44697112,d.d2k) with Rmagic reprocessoring on thumbnails

Comment: exactly, Tiago Francos answer did the trick  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13441569/473040

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/13441569/473040

```
class DocumentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
include CarrierWave::RMagick
#...

    version :thumb do
      process :remove_animation
      process :resize_to_fill => [300,200]

      #....
    end    

    def remove_animation
      # this will keep only first image of animated gif
      manipulate! do |img, index|
      index == 0 ? img : nil
    end

end
```

thx Padde and Tiago Franco